# UIKit Dynamics: Attachment inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit-dynamics

My table view cells contain a circle in an `UIView`, indicating a value. I want to add the `UIKit Dynamics` attachment behaviour to that circle in order to for it to lag a bit when scrolling.

I don't want to attach the individual cells to each other but only the circle view to the `UITableViewCell`. The rest of the cell should scroll as usual.

Problem: The `UITableViewCell` has its origin always at `(0, 0)`. How can I add the circle to a view that actually does move when scrolling?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. No, but HKTonyLee's answer addresses my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it to work. The `UITableView` moves the coordinate system of every cell and of all views contained within that cell. Therefor I needed to manually move my view inside the `UITableViewCell` during scrolling while still referring to the initial anchor point.

The table view controller:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    BOOL scrollingUp = '\0';
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        scrollingUp = YES;
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        scrollingUp = NO;
    }

    NSInteger offset = 64; // To compensate for the navigation bar.

    if (scrollingUp) {
        offset = offset - scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }
    else {
        offset = offset + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    }

    // Limit the offset so the views will not disappear during fast scrolling.
    if (offset > 10) {
        offset = 10;
    }
    else if (offset < -10) {
        offset = -10;
    }

    // lastContentOffset is an instance variable.
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

    for (UITableViewCell *cell in self.tableView.visibleCells) {  
        // Use CoreAnimation to prohibit flicker.          
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"Display notification" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
        [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];

        cell.view.frame = CGRectMake(cell.view.frame.origin.x, offset, cell.view.frame.size.width, cell.view.frame.size.height);
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        [cell.dynamicAnimator updateItemUsingCurrentState:cell.view];
    }
}
```

The table view cell:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    // _view is the animated UIView.
    UIDynamicItemBehavior *viewBehavior = [[UIDynamicItemBehavior alloc] initWithItems:@[_view]];
    viewBehavior.elasticity = 0.9f;

    UIAttachmentBehavior *attachmentBehaviorView = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:_view attachedToAnchor:CGPointMake(_anchorView.frame.origin.x + _anchorView.frame.size.width / 2.0f, _anchorView.frame.origin.y + _anchorView.frame.size.height / 2.0f)];
    attachmentBehaviorView.damping = 8.0f;
    attachmentBehaviorView.frequency = 4.0f;
    attachmentBehaviorView.length = 0.0f;

    [_dynamicAnimator addBehavior:viewBehavior];
    [_dynamicAnimator addBehavior:attachmentBehaviorView];
}
```

Comment: Always call super in layoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `anchorPoint` of `UIAttachmentBehavior` during `-[scrollViewDidScroll:]`. You may refer to the following code snippet:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIDynamicAnimator *animator = [[UIDynamicAnimator alloc] initWithReferenceView:self.view];

    UIAttachmentBehavior *behavior1 = [[UIAttachmentBehavior alloc] initWithItem:self.circleView
                                          attachedToAnchor:[self tableViewAnchor]];
    behavior1.length = 10.0;
    behavior1.damping = 0.3;
    behavior1.frequency = 2.5;

    [animator addBehavior:behavior1];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    behavior1.anchorPoint = [self.tableView convertPoint:[self tableViewAnchor] toView:self.view];
}

- (CGPoint)tableViewAnchor
{
    return CGPointMake(160.0, 154.0);   // return your target coordination w.r.t. the table view
}
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. I achieved the effect by manually moving the respective `UIView` in `scrollViewDidScroll:scrollView`. Cf. my response below.