# Scrolling rows effects in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, animation, ios7

I want to make scrolling effect in iOS 7 when scroll up, those rows will move like this gif shows. Please forget the effect when scroll down (because I cannot find a better sample). However, I don't know how to do that although did research, any solutions and open sources are appreciated!

http://d13yacurqjgara.cloudfront.net/users/107759/screenshots/1176252/moments-ios7.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is done by adding Gravity effect to UIKit components. Once you add attachmentBehaviors, you can easily achieve this effect.

You can find a [tutorial help here](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-uikit-dynamics-tutorial/).

There is another solution specific to [UITableViewCells here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21098116/1891327).

Comment: Thank you, I just found this https://github.com/onevcat/VVSpringCollectionViewFlowLayout . I'm giving it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It  is advisable to use a `UITableView` & on reload table view data animation can be used by the following way to give a bouncing effect during table reload.

```
[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Corresponding row animation effect should be given here.

For delay in scroll for each section as seen in the gif, I would suggest you to go ahead with animation for individual cells.

Go through this open source [link](http://www.thinkandbuild.it/animating-uitableview-cells/), this might be useful.

Shall try and get back, in-case I perform the exact animation effect.

Comment: Nice resource, man. Btw, I just found this https://github.com/onevcat/VVSpringCollectionViewFlowLayout .